# Chrome browser cache issue

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I am doing a CSS modifications but I am not seeing those changes changes in the browser even when I clear the history, cache, cookies. I also tried this in incognito mode with the same result.

Comment: have any extensions for that??

Comment: Ask one question at a time. I edited the question to make more sense so you can have more change of getting an answer.